# Scrolling Issue in UITextview in iOS - Glitch and Auto-Scroll Behavior

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview, autoscroll

#### Problem Description

I am currently working on an iOS project (for iPad) using Objective-C, and I've encountered a vexing issue with a `UITextview`. I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot this issue.

#### Reproduction Steps

To replicate the problem, follow these steps:

1. Load a `UITextview` with a significant amount of content, more than 2000 lines.
2. Begin scrolling from the bottom to the top, doing so slowly.
3. After scrolling through 300-400 lines, a glitch occurs in the scroll behavior.
4. The view automatically scrolls all the way to the bottom, leaving extra space at the bottom.

#### Actual Behavior

- The issue I'm facing is described in the reproduction steps. This behavior is inconsistent and problematic for my users.
- When scrolling from top to bottom, there are no issues; the behavior is as expected.
- Scrolling with medium and high speed also works as intended.
- Despite the auto-scroll, the scroll indicator remains at the initial position (for few seconds) where I left it.

#### UI Implementation

- I added a `UITextview` to a ViewController’s `UIView`.
- I've set the constraints for the `UITextview` to pin it to all four sides (leading, trailing, top, and bottom) of its parent `UIView`.

The UI layout itself appears to be correctly configured, but I'm experiencing unexpected scroll behavior as described in the "Actual Behavior" section.

#### Expected Behavior

I expected the `UITextview` to smoothly scroll from bottom to top, allowing me to read and interact with the content without any glitches or auto-scrolling behavior.

Additional Information

- iOS version: Tested in iPad device (iOS 17), iPad Simulator (iOS 15, iOS  16, iOS  17)
- Xcode version: 15.0

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in troubleshooting and resolving this scrolling issue in the UITextview. Thanks in advance for your help!